# model languages skills with ruby on rails and mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm starting to learn RoR and mongodb. I started creating a simple CV application where the users specify what level of expertise they consider themselves to be in a given language (between 1 - 5). The language is a collection

Languages Collection

```
{ 
   {id:A1, language:"English", status:active}, 
   {id:A2, language:"Spanish", status:inactive}
}
```

User Collection

```
{
   {id:U1, name:"User Name", languages:{{id:A1, skill:4},{id:A2, skill:3}}},
   {id:U2, name:"Mac Link", languages:{{id:A1, skill:2},{id:A2, skill:5}}}
}
```

I really don't know how to model this with RoR and mongodb because I need to load the languages collection by default and put a select box to choose the skill level. After loading everything, the user will select a skill level and then, save. The language will not be saved, (it will save another model).

If you could give me some guidance, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

multiple approaches can be used, for instance

the general idea, languages and users are loaded separately. If you need languages, only for displayin purposes (language name which is kept in languages collection), then use mapping as I proposed at the end.
If more sophisticated logic is needed, put it somewhere in Service layer

Hope it helps.

```
class LanguagesRepo
  def load_language_mapping
    languages = mongo_client.search({}).to_a #will array with languages

    languages.inject({}) do |memo, current_language|
      memo[current_language['id']] = current_language
    end   # result will be a hash { 1 => { 'id' => 1, 'language': 'English'} }
  end 
end

class User
    class Language
        include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :id, :skill
end

include ActiveModel::Model

attr_accessor :id, :name, :languages
end

class UserRepo
  def load_user(id)
    json = mongo_client.query(id: id)
    UserMongoParser.new(json).parse #will return properly filled User instance
  end

def save_user(user)
    mongo_client.update({id: user.id}, user.as_json) #depending on what client you use
    #or
    mongo_client.update({id: user.id}, UserMongoSerializer.new(user).serialize) #depending on what client you use
end
```

end

## somewhere in your haml/erb user form file

```
%ul
    user_form.languages.each do |language_item|
        %li
            = user_form.hidden_field :id
            = user_form.label :skill, @languages_mapping[language_item.id]['name'] #will display language name as label
            = user_form.text_field :skill
```